# How do I fetch url with urllib2 without declaring a url scheme?

Tags: python, http, url, urllib2

This might be a stupid question but can i fetch a url with urllib2 without declaring the url scheme like http or https

To clarify instead of writing 'http://blahblah.com' i just want to write 'blahblah.com', is this possible ?

Comment: If it's going to be http or https only, you can just add that as a prefix..

Comment: Without the scheme, how would you know what protocol or port to use? There are literally hundreds of protocols that could be used - just a hostname isn't adequate to tell a dumb system what protocol to choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import urllib2

def open_url_with_default_protocol(*args, **kwargs):
    #  Use the HTTP scheme by default if none is given
    #  pass through all other arguments to urllib2.urlopen

    default_scheme = 'http://'

    url = args[0]
    scheme, address = urllib2.splittype(url)

    if not scheme:
        #  Replace the url in the args tuple by a URL with the default scheme
        args = (default_scheme + args[0],) + args[1:]

    return urllib2.urlopen(*args, **kwargs)
```

So you can do:

```
>>> open_url_with_default_protocol('http://google.com')
<addinfourl at 4496800872 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x10bd92b50>>
>>> open_url_with_default_protocol('google.com')
<addinfourl at 4331750464 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x1027960d0>>
```

Note that this function will still fail if you pass it a URL of the form '//google.com', because it assumes that if there is no scheme, there is no leading double forward slash.